# Посчитать среднее по значениям в столбце в python

Tags: python, pandas

Итак, есть исходный DF:

`Time   x1  x2
0   5   6
1   4   5
2   6   6
3   6   5
0   9   8
1   4   6
2   6   5
3   4   6`

Нужно посчитать среднее для x1 и x2 для каждого из значений в Time.
То есть на выходе хочу получить:

`Time   x1  x2
0   7   7
1   4   5,5
2   6   5,5
3   5   5,5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
df.groupby('Time').mean()
```